# Jquery show/hide/toggle elements "near by"

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to set this up so that "Click me 1" only shows "Expand me 1", "Click me 2" only shows "Expand me 2", etc. What I have now makes each one toggle everything. I think I need to use `$(this)` but nowhere I've put it has worked.

Markup

```
<div class="submission">
    <ul>
        <li class="click">Click me 1</li>
        <li>foo</li>
        <li>bar</li>
        <li class="expand">Expand me 1</li>
    </ul>
</div>

<div class="submission">
    <ul>
        <li class="click">Click me 2</li>
        <li>foo</li>
        <li>bar</li>
        <li class="expand">Expand me 2</li>
    </ul>
</div>

<div class="submission">
    <ul>
        <li class="click">Click me 3</li>
        <li>foo</li>
        <li>bar</li>
        <li class="expand">Expand me 3</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Jquery

```
$(document).ready(function() {
        $(".submission").find(".click").click(function() {
            $(".expand").slideToggle();
    });
});
```

CSS

```
.expand {display: none;}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/4k9uukL8/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `.parent()` selector

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/4k9uukL8/2/)

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".submission .click").click(function() {
        $(this).parent().find(".expand").slideToggle();
    });
});
```

More information in [documentation](https://api.jquery.com/parent/)

Answer (score 0):

You want to target one of the following sibling element so

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".submission .click").click(function() {
    $(this).nextAll(".expand").slideToggle();
    //or $(this).siblings(".expand").slideToggle();    
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="submission">
  <ul>
    <li class="click">Click me 1</li>
    <li>foo</li>
    <li>bar</li>
    <li class="expand">Expand me 1</li>
  </ul>
</div>

<div class="submission">
  <ul>
    <li class="click">Click me 2</li>
    <li>foo</li>
    <li>bar</li>
    <li class="expand">Expand me 2</li>
  </ul>
</div>

<div class="submission">
  <ul>
    <li class="click">Click me 3</li>
    <li>foo</li>
    <li>bar</li>
    <li class="expand">Expand me 3</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try utilizing [Next Siblings Selector ("prev ~ siblings")](http://api.jquery.com/next-siblings-selector/) selector `$("~ .expand", this)` within `click` handler to call `.slideToggle()`

```js
$(".submission .click").click(function() {
  $("~ .expand", this).slideToggle()
})
```

```css
.expand {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js">
</script>
<div class="submission">
  <ul>
    <li class="click">Click me 1</li>
    <li>foo</li>
    <li>bar</li>
    <li class="expand">Expand me 1</li>
  </ul>
</div>

<div class="submission">
  <ul>
    <li class="click">Click me 2</li>
    <li>foo</li>
    <li>bar</li>
    <li class="expand">Expand me 2</li>
  </ul>
</div>

<div class="submission">
  <ul>
    <li class="click">Click me 3</li>
    <li>foo</li>
    <li>bar</li>
    <li class="expand">Expand me 3</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Pekka's answer is probably the simplest (and therefore best).

An alternate could be to use "closest" when not addressing the immediate parent.

```
$(this).closest(".submission").find(".expand").slideToggle();
```